# How to add plugin in build.phonegap.com

Tags: android, iphone, git, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a plugin in this github url:

https://github.com/AvijitChakraborty/phonegapStart

Now i want to add this plugin in phonegap in https://build.phonegap.com/plugins#add

There it is asking for a Plugin Git Repository URL. I have given https://github.com/AvijitChakraborty/phonegapStart . And I have submited it by accepting the condition but it is telling me **Git Repository URL is invalid**. What is wrong i am doing? Thanks in advnce.

Comment: Can you give the command used??

Comment: I didn't use any command. What is the command i should use? @user1562655

Answer (score 0):

Plugins submitted to PhoneGap Build need to follow a certain structure. You can find the specific information here:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugman/blob/master/README.md

You cannot add outside plugins to your project only, you have to submit them to PhoneGap Build to be added to the list of approved plugins for all PhoneGap Build users.

You can use the Cordova or PhoneGap command line client(s) to build projects on your local machine and then you can use any plugin you wish.